# Using postMessage in reloaded iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I have iframe with simple form (provided by third-party vendor).
The content of iframe reloads after form is submitted with confirmation page.
On that page I asked provider to add this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.parent.postMessage('mailing_list_confirmation','http://originURL.com/');
    },100) </script>
```

I the top window I have:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on('mailing_list_confirmation',function(){
          console.log("iframe_message");
       });
    });
</script>
```

Nothing complicated. I tried also with plain JS.
I tried this on my localhost (2 different domains) and it was working well. The difference was that the iframe was originally loaded. In this case the iframe content is new page.
Is there any other reason why this might not work?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, check the domain your posting to is what you think it is and not www.originaldomain.com.

Comment: Should that domain name include http:// or not? 
Can this be because the domain is behind password (it is staging site) and cannot be open without providing username and password?

Comment: It should be the protocol, domain and port

Comment: Thanks, It's on standard port (80), but it's behind authentication. I guess this is a stopper.

Comment: Auth should not effect it

Comment: This is not Auth to the site, but on server level to open the staging in the browser.

Comment: I mean it is Http authentication